# Is this Sql injection proof Asp.net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can somebody tell me the pros and cons of this code? I know I can use stored procedures instead, but would it be easy to SQL inject this code considering I had a textbox where admins could input the commentid?

```
string commentId = a.Text;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForumDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
string sql = "DELETE FROM Comment WHERE Comment.commentId = @commentid";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentid", commentId);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Just try it out and type into your textbox something like `' and 1 = 1; drop table Comment;--`. If it works you´re open to SQL-injection, otherwise not.

Comment: Avoiding SQL Injection is really about making sure that *data* and *code* aren't mixed together, such that some data could be mistaken for code. You're doing that here by keeping the code (`sql`) separate from the data (`cmd.Parameters`).

Comment: @HimBromBeere - that only tells you whether you're vulnerable to *one specific form* of injection. It failing to work doesn't tell you that the code is *safe* from injection issues.

Comment: This is safe @Adrian. Well done - great code. Although consider reading https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ as well.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True, but the question is merely about if the code is vulnerable, but about why even using sql-paramaters at all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it looks fine, since you're using paramterized sql.  However, you haven't given your table an alias, so I thing your sql should be

`DELETE FROM Comment WHERE commentId = @commentid`

As well as protecting you from sql injection attacks, Sql Server will know that this sql may be called again with different parameters, so can cache an efficient execution plan for it.

As an aside, you should always dispose of connections after using them.

```cs
    string commentId = a.Text;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["ForumDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string sql = "DELETE FROM Comment WHERE Comment.commentId = @commentid";
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentid", commentId);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there is a fair amount of code for such a simple operation.  You may wish to take a look at [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/), which will remove a lot of these issues.  There are many libraries to help you, which are off-topic here, but its a lightweight, popular one

Comment: gah! Thanks.  tbh, use dapper and be done with it ;)

Comment: "Closed - primarily opinion based :p"

Answer (score 0):

Pros:

- Good thing is you are using parameters for command which is sql injection safe.

Cons:

- Not well written.
- Not using function for CRUD. Always Use functions to do CRUD operation.
- No Use of Using block. Always use using block, so you don't need to dispose connection & command. You don't need to manually close it.

Use following code in DataAccessLayer.

```
public void DeleteComment(int commentId)
{
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForumDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql = "DELETE FROM Comment WHERE Comment.commentId = @commentid";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentid", commentId);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        } 
}
```

You can write connection open code in separate function too.

Check this article for more detail:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813965/Preventing-SQL-Injection-Attack-ASP-NET-Part-I